# How can I change the color of the gridlines of a Grid in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a `Grid` (not a DataGrid, but a real Grid), with `GridLines` set to `True`. How can I change the color of the gridlines?
Hardcoded in XAML is ok, since it is just for development-reasons.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" />
```

Comment: Do you mean a Grid, or a DataGrid? I don't see a GridLines property on Grid.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sorry, can't be done with ShowGridLines - you need to style the elements contained.

**Exhibit A:**

MSDN docs say "Only dotted lines are available because this property is intended as a design tool to debug layout problems and is not intended for use in production quality code. If you want lines inside a Grid, style the elements within the Grid to have borders."

**Exhibit B - The WPF Source Code:**

Notice the Brushes.Blue and Brushes.Yellow hard-coded in this sealed internal class which System.Windows.Controls.Grid uses to draw the lines.

From Grid.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to render grid lines. 
    /// </summary>
    internal class GridLinesRenderer : DrawingVisual 
    { 
        /// <summary>
        /// Static initialization 
        /// </summary>
        static GridLinesRenderer()
        {
            s_oddDashPen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, c_penWidth); 
            DoubleCollection oddDashArray = new DoubleCollection();
            oddDashArray.Add(c_dashLength); 
            oddDashArray.Add(c_dashLength); 
            s_oddDashPen.DashStyle = new DashStyle(oddDashArray, 0);
            s_oddDashPen.DashCap = PenLineCap.Flat; 
            s_oddDashPen.Freeze();

            s_evenDashPen = new Pen(Brushes.Yellow, c_penWidth);
            DoubleCollection evenDashArray = new DoubleCollection(); 
            evenDashArray.Add(c_dashLength);
            evenDashArray.Add(c_dashLength); 
            s_evenDashPen.DashStyle = new DashStyle(evenDashArray, c_dashLength); 
            s_evenDashPen.DashCap = PenLineCap.Flat;
            s_evenDashPen.Freeze(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var T = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.Grid+GridLinesRenderer," +
    " PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

var GLR = Activator.CreateInstance(T);
GLR.GetType().GetField("s_oddDashPen", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(GLR, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0));
GLR.GetType().GetField("s_evenDashPen", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(GLR, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0));

myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
```

Comment: Thanks +1 . 

wouldn't of thought of doing that. 

By using reflection you can by pass the fact that the class is internal ?

Comment: If you set both pens to orange, it turns out pretty easy on the eyes :)

Answer (score 7):

This answer is not how to actually change the GridLines, but how to make it look like you did in a very simple way. I am sure others have better ways to do this, but here is how I accomplished showing my gridlines.

```
<Grid Height="115" Margin="0,0,0,0" ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/> 
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">                      
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">        
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
```

Create a border for your column definitions or grid definitions and set the Grid.Column property to whatever you wish. Then you can set your color, thickness, or style. Sweet and simple. Hope this helps someone else!

Here is an image of this grid:

[image]

Comment: The two vertical borders in the middle of the grid will actually have a thickness of 2 and not 1 if you zoom in. These two lines will visually appear thicker than the rest. This artifact can be corrected by adding `Margin="-1,0.-1,0"` to the second border element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedGridLine" Color="#FFFF4444" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueGridLine" Color="#554444FF"/>
</Window.Resources>

<my:DataGrid VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource RedGridLine}"
        HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource BlueGridLine}" >
...
</my:DataGrid>
```

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0202b0dd-38d9-4ad7-8576-d115922aeeec/

Comment: Funny. This actually helped me becuz I was searching for DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

An extension of [igalk474's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869736/1441398), used as:

```xml
<FixedPage.Resources>
  <local:GridLinesRenderer x:Key="glr" StrokeColor="Black" StrokeWidth="1.0" />
</FixedPage.Resources>

...

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
...
</Grid>
```

Where `local` is the local assembly, and `FixedPage` is any [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx).

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace mynamespace.xaml {
    public class GridLinesRenderer : DependencyObject {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "StrokeWidth", typeof(double), typeof(GridLinesRenderer), new PropertyMetadata(1.0, OnPropertyChanged)
        );

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "StrokeColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(GridLinesRenderer), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, OnPropertyChanged)
        );

        public double StrokeWidth {
            get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public SolidColorBrush StrokeColor {
            get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(StrokeColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public GridLinesRenderer() {
            OnPropertyChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs());
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            Type T = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.Grid+GridLinesRenderer," +
                "PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
            var glr = Activator.CreateInstance(T);
            Pen glrPen = new Pen(((GridLinesRenderer)source).StrokeColor, ((GridLinesRenderer)source).StrokeWidth);
            glr.GetType().GetField("s_oddDashPen", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(glr, glrPen);
            glr.GetType().GetField("s_evenDashPen", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(glr, glrPen);
        }

    }
}
```