# How can I get a Grid to draw Borders for blank cells?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, grid, gridlines

I have an ItemsControl which uses a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, and sets the Grid.Column and Grid.Row on the `ItemContainerStyle` to position data items in the grid

Is there a way to either add GridLines to the Grid, or to fill in the blank cells with a Border?

Right now I have `ShowGridLines` set to True which makes the dotted lines, however I want Horizontal lines to show up, and I'd prefer solid GridLines

[image: Screenshot]

There is a rather large amount of XAML, but here's a screenshot of how my XAML is laid out:
[image: XAML Layout]

Comment: What tool did you use for your layout?

Comment: @AdamBT [Balsamiz](https://balsamiq.com/), they have a [free web demo](https://webdemo.balsamiq.com/) that I usually use

Comment: Nice ... thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, styling the grid lines can't be done. Atleast not in an easy way. See the following question for an explanation: [How can I change the color of the gridlines of a Grid in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606220/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-gridlines-of-a-grid-in-wpf)

> MSDN docs say "Only dotted lines are available because this property
> is intended as a design tool to debug layout problems and is not
> intended for use in production quality code. If you want lines inside
> a Grid, style the elements within the Grid to have borders."

**Edit:** If you want the borders you can create a custom `Grid` and draw the `GridLines` in `OnRender` method of the control.

```cs
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    namespace BorderGridControl
    {
        public class GridControl : Grid
        {
            #region Properties
            public bool ShowCustomGridLines
            {
                get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCustomGridLinesProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ShowCustomGridLinesProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCustomGridLinesProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCustomGridLines", typeof(bool), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

            
            public Brush GridLineBrush
            {
                get { return (Brush)GetValue(GridLineBrushProperty); }
                set { SetValue(GridLineBrushProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLineBrushProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("GridLineBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

            public double GridLineThickness
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(GridLineThicknessProperty); }
                set { SetValue(GridLineThicknessProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLineThicknessProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("GridLineThickness", typeof(double), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0));
            #endregion

            protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
            {
                if (ShowCustomGridLines)
                {
                    foreach (var rowDefinition in RowDefinitions)
                    {
                        dc.DrawLine(new Pen(GridLineBrush, GridLineThickness), new Point(0, rowDefinition.Offset), new Point(ActualWidth, rowDefinition.Offset));
                    }

                    foreach (var columnDefinition in ColumnDefinitions)
                    {
                        dc.DrawLine(new Pen(GridLineBrush, GridLineThickness), new Point(columnDefinition.Offset, 0), new Point(columnDefinition.Offset, ActualHeight));
                    }
                    dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, new Pen(GridLineBrush, GridLineThickness), new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
                }
                base.OnRender(dc);
            }
            static GridControl()
            {
                DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridControl)));
            }
        }
    }
```

I Tried it out and it seems to be working great.

Here an example of using:

```xml
    <controls:GridControl ShowCustomGridLines="True"
                          GridLineBrush="Red"
                          GridLineThickness="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </controls:GridControl>
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that. I'm beginning to think I need to create something in the Loaded event that fills all blank cells with a Border. Or perhaps overlay two grids on top of eachother and have the top one transparent and the bottom one be filled with borders.

Comment: Are you creating the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` in Xaml or in code depending on the items?

Comment: In the XAML. Each "Row" is actually its own `Grid` with 7 Columns.

Comment: @Rachel: See my updated answer, I believe this is, by far, the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that looks quite promising! I'll check it out Monday (home now and have a strict no-work-from-home policy)

Comment: That worked out great, thanks Meleak! I actually adjusted the ShowCustomGridLines to be of type `DataGridGridLinesVisibility` instead of `bool` so I could specify if I want horizontal or vertical lines too :)