# Wpf: How to color portion of a rectangle based on percentage?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to split a rectangle and color the various portions based on percentage, I've looked around and found some solutions but I can't understand which one is the best option for what I need. I post here an image showing what I need.

[image]

please can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: which solutions did you find and why do you think they are not optimal?

Comment: @ASh I found some but I don't understand how to operate..so I was wondering if anyone can provide me some sort of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example fill a `Grid` with `Border` elements:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2 2 2 0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Red" />
    <Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Border Background="Green" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Grid layout? You can define the rows using percentages and then define for each row a border and background color. 
You can read more about Grid in the link. [Grid Tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/)

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244457/how-to-set-row-border-and-background-color-in-wpf-grid). I think the option of placing a Border inside each cell should be a good fit here.

Comment: i've tried but I can't understand how to implement what I need..can you provide some sort of code?

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a code sample at the moment. I've edited the answer to include a reference to a similar answered question, hope it helps.